# How do I write Java code to save PWD directory to new file using Perl?

Tags: java, perl

How to write Java code to save pwd (present working directory) to new file.

In java , Use Perl script inside java code itself.

Comment: Are you trying to save the PWD using perl?  Or do you want to save the PWD from a Java program, and also run a perl script from the program?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Java only. For example [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class.

```
Path pwd = Paths.get("");
System.out.println(pwd.toAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: thank u for solution, But im looking  in java code  we will pass List<String> cmdlist= new ArrayList<String>();    cmdlist.add("echo '#!/bin/perl ' > " + newfileLoc);   cmdlist.add("echo ' pwd' >> " +newfileLoc);

Comment: List<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>();
           cmdlist.add("echo '#!/bin/sh' > " + abc.txt);
            cmdlist.add("echo 'pwd' >> " + abc.txt);
            cmdlist.add("echo 'output=$?' >>" + abc.txt);
            cmdlist.add("echo 'exit $output' >>"+ abc.txt);    this i wanted to convert to perl script

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) or the [Process API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). 
You can then just call [process.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) to get [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl script.pl");
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\.");
        String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        System.out.println(result);

        //Creating a text file to write the output of the executed command
        //note that this will overwrite the file if it already exists
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.write(result);
        writer.close();

        // EDIT: 
        // writing commands to file name abc.txt
        List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmdList.add("echo '#!/bin/sh' >> ");
        cmdList.add("echo 'pwd' >> ");
        cmdList.add("echo 'output=$?' >>");
        cmdList.add("echo 'exit $output' >>");

        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("abc.txt");
        for (String cmd : cmdList) {
            w.println(cmd);
        }
        w.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: if i want to write content of script.pl in Java, How we can do that ?

Comment: @User1 do you want to write the output of executed command to a file from your java code ?
or you just want to write the content of the script.pl ? if yes then where you want to write that ? to a file from your java code ?

Comment: thank u, im looking for output of executed cmd to new file

Comment: @User1 I have edited my answer, now you can write the output of the executed command to `output.txt` file.

Comment: thank u...    how to convert shell script written in java code to perl script in java                                                                                                            List<String> cmdlist = new ArrayList<String>();
           cmdlist.add("echo '#!/bin/sh' > " + abc.txt);
            cmdlist.add("echo 'pwd' >> " + abc.txt);
            cmdlist.add("echo 'output=$?' >>" + abc.txt);
            cmdlist.add("echo 'exit $output' >>"+ abc.txt);  i wanted to convert this to perl using java code

Comment: @User1 do you want to append some line in `abc.txt` like you said do you want to add list of command to a perl script file ?

Comment: then you just need to a new print writer object with new file and write the commands one by one. if you have a list that has the commands then iterate through the list and append it to the file. its pretty simple...
try that, if you still find that difficult then comment here I will edit and add that part in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for support.   These piece of two codes.. I have to convert to perl . ca you please help me.

Comment: String fileLoc= "/tmp/abc";

                cmd.add("echo '#!/bin/sh' > " + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo 'CAT_VAL=`cat " + DB_LOG + File.separator + "spf.txt"
    + "`' >> " + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo 'if [ $CAT_VAL = \"SPFILE\" ]; then' >> " + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo '   exit 0' >> " + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo 'else' >> " + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo '  echo ' Failed .'' >> "
    + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo '   exit 2' >> " + fileLoc);
  cmd.add("echo 'fi' >> " + fileLoc);

Comment: is this >> behaviors is different in shell script and perl ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, if you want to append command you have to do like that.
I don't have any idea about `>>` behaviors different in shell and perl.

Comment: yaa sure It will more help full.. But I wanted to convert above script code to  Perl script.  i.e abc file should be content of perl script

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

my $CAT_VAL=`cat /tmp/.../spf.txt`;
if($CAT_VA eq "SPFILE") {
exit;
}else {
 print "failed ";
exit ;
}

Comment: the above script code should be there in abc file.. i wanted write above shell script to perl script in java.. finally abc contains perlscript code.

Comment: where is that stored in your java code ? in a String variable ? if yes then just w.write(variable) will do the work.
or are you wanting to convert a shell script code into a perl script code using java ? in that case I can't help you.

Comment: But actually this cmds should execute through  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds); Actually i wanted shell script code into perl script using java